# Using Sharepoint Web Services to perform people search

Tags: web-services

Iam trying to do a People Search over the Webservices: _vti_bin/search.asmx

This Is how I ended up:

```
  <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Query xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
      <queryXml>
<QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query" Revision="1000">
<Query domain="QDomain">
 <SupportedFormats><Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document</Format></SupportedFormats>
 <Context>
   <QueryText language="en-US" type="MSSQLFT"><![CDATA[ SELECT Size, Rank, Path, Title, Description, Write FROM portal..scope() WHERE  ( ("SCOPE" = 'Personen') )   ORDER BY "Rank" DESC ]]></QueryText>
 </Context>
 <Range><StartAt>1</StartAt><Count>20</Count></Range>
 <EnableStemming>false</EnableStemming>
 <TrimDuplicates>true</TrimDuplicates>
 <IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>true</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>
 <ImplicitAndBehavior>true</ImplicitAndBehavior>
 <IncludeRelevanceResults>true</IncludeRelevanceResults>
 <IncludeSpecialTermResults>true</IncludeSpecialTermResults>
 <IncludeHighConfidenceResults>true</IncludeHighConfidenceResults>
</Query></QueryPacket>
</queryXml>
    </Query>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

This Was also an option:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Query xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
      <queryXml>
       <QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query">
           <Query>
            <Context>
            <QueryText language="en-US" type="MSSQLFT">
            SELECT * FROM SCOPE() WHERE "scope"= 'People'    
            </QueryText>
           </Context>
           <Range><Count>20</Count></Range>
           </Query>
            </QueryPacket>
             </queryXml> 
           </Query> 
         </soap:Body> 
       </soap:Envelope>
```

I only need the Username or some Information.
What Iam doing wrong.
How schooled be the Syntax and the Namespace?

Update:

So I ended up doing :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
<Query xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
<queryXml>
&lt;QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query"&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;SupportedFormats&gt;&lt;Format revision="1"&gt;urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document&lt;/Format&gt;&lt;/SupportedFormats&gt;&lt;Context&gt;&lt;QueryText language="en-US" type="STRING"&gt;samadzai&lt;/QueryText&gt;&lt;/Context&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/QueryPacket&gt;
</queryXml>
    </Query>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Does anybody know why I should use &gt than > ????

Is there any possibility to have an standardized work on share point web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use &gt because > is an xml character representing the closing of an item, while &gt is a text representation of a greater than symbol.

The xml needs to be set up within the bounds of its own syntax, while the text (the query data being transported) needs to be completely independent of it.

Unfortunately I do not know enough about web services to help you better understand any other aspects of this.